# HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'client'

Tags: django-testing, django-tests

Django 1.9.6

I'd like to write some unit test for checking redirection.

Could you help me understand what am I doing wrongly here.

Thank you in advance.

The test:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http.request import HttpRequest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class GeneralTest(TestCase):

    def test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page(self):
        user = User(username='anonymous', email='vvv@mail.ru', password='ttrrttrr')
        user.is_active = False        
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.user = user
        hpv = HomePageView()
        response = hpv.get(request)
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("auth_login"))
```

The result:

### ERROR: test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page (general.tests.GeneralTest)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/workspace/photoarchive/photoarchive/general/tests.py", line 44, in test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("auth_login"))
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 326, in assertRedirects
    redirect_response = response.client.get(path, QueryDict(query),
AttributeError: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'client'

---

Ran 3 tests in 0.953s

What pdb says:

```
-> self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("auth_login"))
(Pdb) response
<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/accounts/login/">
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a client to the response object. See the updated code below.

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http.request import HttpRequest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class GeneralTest(TestCase):

    def test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page(self):
        user = User(username='anonymous', email='vvv@mail.ru', password='ttrrttrr')
        user.is_active = False        
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.user = user
        hpv = HomePageView()
        response = hpv.get(request)
        response.client = Client()
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("auth_login"))
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are directly calling your view's `get` directly rather than using the built-in `Client`. When you use the test client, you get your client instance back in the response, presumably for cases such as this where you want to check/fetch a redirect.

One solution would be to use the client to fetch the response from your view. Another is to stick a client in the response as mentioned above.

A third option is tell `assertRedirects` not to fetch the redirect. There is no need for client if you don't ask the assertion to fetch the redirect. That's done by adding `fetch_redirect_response=False` to your assertion.